# JavaScript onClick() event not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I made a function with JavaScript to add other fields in the page, but when I click the button that should fire the event nothing happens. Also I don't see any error from Fire-bug

```
<!--add other charge fields button-->
<div class="form-group" id="newf">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  name="new" onclick="addField()">
        <?php echo $lang['add-field-button']; ?>
    </button>
</div>
```

JavaScript function is in the same page:

```
<!-- script to add more fields -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function addField() {
var field =
'<fieldset>'+
'<legend><?php echo $lang['addmonth-add-charge'] ?></legend>'+
'<div class="form-group">'+
'<label for="charge"><?php echo $lang['charge-formlabel']; ?></label>'+
'<input type="text" id="charge" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['placeholder-addcharge']; ?>" class="form-control" name="charge[]">'+
'<p class="help-block"><?php echo $lang['charge-form-description']; ?></p>'+
'</div>'+
'<!--/end charge-->'+
'<div class="form-group">'+
'<label for="description"><?php echo $lang['description-formlabel']; ?></label>'+
'<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="description" name="description[]" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['placeholder-adddescription']; ?>" ></textarea>'+
'<label class="control-label" for="description"><?php echo $lang['description-formlabel']; ?></label>'+
'<div class="controls">'+
'<textarea class="span8" rows="5" id="description" name="description[]" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['placeholder-adddescription']; ?>" ></textarea>'+
'</div>'+
'<!--/end description-->'+
'<div class="form-group input-group">'+
'<label for="value"><?php echo $lang['value-formlabel']; ?></label>'+
'<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>'+
'<input type="text" id="value" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['placeholder-addvalue']; ?>" class="form-control" name="value[]"/>'+
'</div>'+
'<!--/end value-->'+
'</fieldset>';
$("#newf").before(field);
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you include the query library?

Comment: what library? its pure javascript

Comment: `$("#newf").before()` isn't pure javascript, it's most likely jQuery.  Also, if any of your `$lang[]` values have single quotes in them, your javascript will break.

Comment: oh i am really sorry, i did include jQuery but just below the script, i fixed it
thank you @JamesThorpe and koljanep

Answer (score 1):

thank you it works now, the problem was the jQuery i included it after the script
thank you all

Answer (score -1):

You need a backslash before each apostrophe, so as not to close the string:

```
<!-- script to add more fields -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function addField() {
var field =
'<fieldset>'+
'<legend><?php echo $lang[\'addmonth-add-charge\'] ?></legend>'+
'<div class="form-group">'+
'<label for="charge"><?php echo $lang[\'charge-formlabel\']; ?></label>'+
'<input type="text" id="charge" placeholder="<?php echo $lang[\'placeholder-addcharge\']; ?>" class="form-control" name="charge[]">'+
'<p class="help-block"><?php echo $lang[\'charge-form-description\']; ?></p>'+
'</div>'+
'<!--/end charge-->'+
'<div class="form-group">'+
'<label for="description"><?php echo $lang[\'description-formlabel\']; ?></label>'+
'<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="description" name="description[]" placeholder="<?php echo $lang[\'placeholder-adddescription\']; ?>" ></textarea>'+
'<label class="control-label" for="description"><?php echo $lang[\'description-formlabel\']; ?></label>'+
'<div class="controls">'+
'<textarea class="span8" rows="5" id="description" name="description[]" placeholder="<?php echo $lang[\'placeholder-adddescription\']; ?>" ></textarea>'+
'</div>'+
'<!--/end description-->'+
'<div class="form-group input-group">'+
'<label for="value"><?php echo $lang[\'value-formlabel\']; ?></label>'+
'<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>'+
'<input type="text" id="value" placeholder="<?php echo $lang[\'placeholder-addvalue\']; ?>" class="form-control" name="value[]"/>'+
'</div>'+
'<!--/end value-->'+
'</fieldset>';
$("#newf").before(field);
}
</script>
```

Comment: That is PHP Code, not going to be there when JS runs.

Comment: Those bits are running server side in PHP.  If the _values they contain_ contain single quotes, then _those values_ need to be escaped.

Comment: Its php written into a var in Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript will break before your onclick.
Cause you mix some Jquery code.
Brief, your issue is elsewhere.

Check the debugger of your webbrowser (cmd+alt+i on ffow & chrome)